Error: 'Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.'
I am trying to create and run a custom expo react-native mobile app. Every time I create a new expo app with npx create-expo-app@latest, I always get the following error when using npx expo run:android;
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

Any information that can help remedy this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
npx expo run:android
Error message:
› Building app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 8 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 33s
13 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 10 up-to-date
Error: C:\Projects\SpeakEasy\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Projects\SpeakEasy\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Projects\SpeakEasy\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:67:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Projects\SpeakEasy\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
...
at spawnAsync (C:\Projects\SpeakEasy\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:28:21)
at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Projects\SpeakEasy\node_modules@expo\cli\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.ts:134:28)
at assembleAsync (C:\Projects\SpeakEasy\node_modules@expo\cli\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.ts:83:16)
at runAndroidAsync (C:\Projects\SpeakEasy\node_modules@expo\cli\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.ts:48:24)
package.json
{
  "name": "speakeasy",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^7.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.0",
    "expo": "~52.0.18",
    "expo-blur": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
    "expo-font": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-haptics": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.3",
    "expo-router": "4.0.11",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-symbols": "~0.2.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.1",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^14.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~4.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
    "react-native-webview": "13.12.5",
    "expo-device": "~7.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.3.12",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.3.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~52.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '35.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '35')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.9.24'

        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin')
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}

